# Hibernate SaveOrUpdate doesn't insert

Tags: hibernate

My requirement is, if there is no data then insert, if there is a data then update it.

I have a json data as input and data receiving in my rest call is:

Service class with json data:

```
mergeAccountDAO.mergeDataList(iterateJson(content));
....
JSONArray jsonArray = (JSONArray) jsonObjectInstance;
for(int i=0; i<jsonArray.size(); i++ ){
   JSONObject jsonObject= (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
   mergeAccountList = buildContent(stringBuilder,jsonObject);
}
List<MergeAccount> mergeAccountList = new ArrayList<MergeAccount>();
private List<MergeAccount> buildContent(StringBuilder stringBuilder, JSONObject jsonObject) {
MergeAccount mergeAccount = new MergeAccount();
String idValue = (jsonObject.get("ID"))==null?"":jsonObject.get("ID").toString();
int id = 0;
if(idValue != null && !idValue.equals("") ){
    id = Integer.parseInt(idValue);
}
...

mergeAccount.setId(id);
mergeAccountList.add(mergeAccount);
return mergeAccountList;
```

DAO class:

```
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public String mergeDataList(List<MergeAccount> mergeAccountList) throws DIException {
    session = sessionFactory.openSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    for (MergeAccount mergeAccount : mergeAccountList) {
        session.saveOrUpdate(mergeAccount);
     }
     tx.commit();
     session.close();       
     return "Success";
}
```

pojo:

```
   @Entity
@Table(name="SIAS_EARNING_ACCOUNT_MAP")
public class MergeAccount  implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @Column(name="EARNING_ACCOUNT_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;


    @Column(name = "AS_ACCOUNT_NAME")
    private String accountName;

    @Column(name = "AS_ACCOUNT_TYPE")
    private String accountType;

    @Column(name = "ACCT_SYSTEM_ID")
    private String accountSystemId;

    @Column(name = "ACCESS_ID")
    private Integer accessId;

    @Column(name = "EMPLID")    
    private String employeeId;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_BY")
    private String createdBy;

    @Column(name = "ERNCD") 
    private String erncd;

    @Column(name = "ERNCD_DESCRIPTION")
    private String erncdDesc;

    @Column(name = "MAPPING_ACTIVE")
    private String mappingActive;

    @Column(name = "AS_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE")
    private String accountActive;

    @Column(name = "MAPPING_EFFECTIVE_DATE")
    private Date mappingEffDate ;

    @Column(name = "MAPPING_NAME")
    private String mappingName;

    @Column(name = "MAPPING_TYPE")
    private String mappingType;

    @Column(name = "TRINET_COMPANY")
    private String trinetCompany;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_BY") 
    private String updatedBy;

    @Column(name = "UPDATED_DATE")
    private Date updateDate ;

    @Column(name = "CREATED_DATE")
    private Date createdDate ;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

          //getter/setter for all fields
```

Console:

```
Hibernate: update SIAS_EARNING_ACCOUNT_MAP set ACCESS_ID=?, AS_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE=?, AS_ACCOUNT_NAME=?, ACCT_SYSTEM_ID=?, AS_ACCOUNT_TYPE=?, CREATED_BY=?, CREATED_DATE=?, EMPLID=?, ERNCD=?, ERNCD_DESCRIPTION=?, MAPPING_ACTIVE=?, MAPPING_EFFECTIVE_DATE=?, MAPPING_NAME=?, MAPPING_TYPE=?, TRINET_COMPANY=?, UPDATED_DATE=?, UPDATED_BY=? where EARNING_ACCOUNT_ID=?
Hibernate: update SIAS_EARNING_ACCOUNT_MAP set ACCESS_ID=?, AS_ACCOUNT_ACTIVE=?, AS_ACCOUNT_NAME=?, ACCT_SYSTEM_ID=?, AS_ACCOUNT_TYPE=?, CREATED_BY=?, CREATED_DATE=?, EMPLID=?, ERNCD=?, ERNCD_DESCRIPTION=?, MAPPING_ACTIVE=?, MAPPING_EFFECTIVE_DATE=?, MAPPING_NAME=?, MAPPING_TYPE=?, TRINET_COMPANY=?, UPDATED_DATE=?, UPDATED_BY=? where EARNING_ACCOUNT_ID=?
```

my json file:

```
[
{
"ID":"101",
"Company":"BEG22",
"Account":"1004",
"Deptid":"13",
"Location":"SM"
...
},

{
"ID":"102",
"Company":"BEG22",
"Account":"1004",
"Deptid":"13",
"Location":"SM"
...
}
]
```

whenever I run again and again no data is getting inserted since it runs only update statement. Data is empty in db.

**EDIT**

column EARNING_ACCOUNT_ID is a sequence in oracle table. Always have some sequence no.

Comment: Your code is building a new mergeAccountList on each iteration through the for loop on the JSONArray.  How is this working at all, as the collection passed to mergeDataList should have at most 1 object?  Also, in "hibernate saveorupdate inserts twice" which you recently asked+deleted, you marked it as JPA. Are you able to use the JPA merge api?  This is a good fit if you are populating the ID and any attributes you want to synchronize into the database as it is required to check if it exists and insert or update appropriately.

Comment: @Chris, mergeAccountList, I moved it above method name which is same as a global variable in Java, It will not create multiple lists, for better readability I have kept it there. with work around solution, Code is working fine If I use save and update seperatley but problem is saveOrUpdate is the issue.  You mean to use the JPA merge api?. I haven't tried.

Answer (score 0):

SaveOrUpdate works based on ID.

If there is an ID, updates
otherwise inserts.

Comment: I have an id and corresponding column is EARNING_ACCOUNT_ID, shown in above pojo class. where it says "If there is an ID, updates otherwise inserts."?

Comment: Sorry... I tried to find the whole information but didn't. here is the IPA for Session.saveOrUpdate http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#saveOrUpdate%28java.lang.Object%29 . I haven't used plain hibernate for year but basically, if you have an ID, hibernate will update your record, if Id is empty, it will create one and insert your record. The other two equivalent methods are save(Object) or update(Object). saveOrUpdate is more flexible but there is a lil performance problem as it needs to figure out if it should save or update.